# Maria DB Server Stopped By 'oom-kill' status=9/KILL in Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, If possible provide simple solution?

Tags: database, wordpress, mariadb, mariadb-10.6

[Screenshot of Failed MariaDB When Checking Status via CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvRH5.png)

**Here is Text If Not possible to read above:**

```
root@ip-172-31-41-95:~# systemctl status mariadb
× mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.6.12 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: oom-kill) since Fri 2023-10-06 13:45:36 IST; 2min 11s ago
       Docs: man:mariadbd(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
    Process: 524 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mariadbd $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=killed, signal=KILL)
   Main PID: 524 (code=killed, signal=KILL)
     Status: "Taking your SQL requests now..."
        CPU: 45min 25.240s

Oct 03 06:24:52 ip-172-31-41-95 /etc/mysql/debian-start[818]: Upgrading MySQL tables if necessary.
Oct 03 06:24:52 ip-172-31-41-95 /etc/mysql/debian-start[863]: Triggering myisam-recover for all MyISAM tables and aria-recover for all Aria tables
Oct 05 20:43:17 ip-172-31-41-95 mariadbd[524]: 2023-10-05 20:43:17 116509 [Warning] Access denied for user 'username_here'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Oct 05 20:44:00 ip-172-31-41-95 mariadbd[524]: 2023-10-05 20:44:00 116703 [Warning] Access denied for user 'username_here'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Oct 05 20:45:13 ip-172-31-41-95 mariadbd[524]: 2023-10-05 20:45:13 117067 [Warning] Access denied for user 'username_here'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Oct 05 20:48:24 ip-172-31-41-95 mariadbd[524]: 2023-10-05 20:48:24 118280 [Warning] Access denied for user 'username_here'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Oct 06 13:45:36 ip-172-31-41-95 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: A process of this unit has been killed by the OOM killer.
Oct 06 13:45:36 ip-172-31-41-95 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Oct 06 13:45:36 ip-172-31-41-95 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
Oct 06 13:45:36 ip-172-31-41-95 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Consumed 45min 25.240s CPU time.
```

My MariaDB Server stopped again in 2 days automatically so i want proper solution.

Comment: so you ran out of memory. How much do you have? What do you have configured `my_print_defaults --mysqld`? Do you monitor memory over time and general activity? If there's no easy explaination then maybe it could be a bug. Upgrading might be a quick way to see if you still run out of memory.

Comment: From the OS Command Prompt, can you post TEXT of 1st page of results from either HTOP or TOP?  This will answer the question of HOW MUCH MEMORY is available on your host.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME, if possible. If not just after startup will be better than nothing.
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: The server machine you use for MariaDB doesn't have enough RAM, so ubuntu's Out Of Memory Killer process killed MariaDB.  The quickest solution to this problem is to run it on a bigger, and more expensive, VM. This version of MariaDB has some auto configuration capability, so it's possible you have manually configured something like the buffer pool to be too large.